# If statement to change font in VB

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro, and I'd like part of it to change the font to 10 after a button press if it was set less than 10 originally. I've gotten most of it to work, but the If statement doesn't seem to be taking, even though it makes sense logically and it's not throwing any errors. All other parts of the function are working correctly, so I believe that the below line is the issue, but I'm not familiar enough with VB to figure out what. I would love some assistance, thanks!

Here's the code in question:
`If .Cells.Font.Size < 10 Then .Cells.Font.Size = 10`

Comment: The answer will depend on what your `With` is referencing

Comment: You should post all relevant code.  I suspect that you are either referencing a different worksheet than you think or the font is being altered later in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess as to your issue, since I don't know what your `With` statement is referencing or what your layout is:

If the `Font.Size` is not consistent across a multi-cell range, then `Font.Size` returns `Null`.

You could possibly loop through cells if needed, or maybe just check the size of one cell, depending on your layout.

To simplify, you could first check `If IsNull(.Cells.Font.Size)` to verify that a loop or some alternate logic is in fact needed.